# Paypal recurring payments lionite

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

I'm using the [Lionite PayPal](http://www.binpress.com/c/20/14808) class to handle PayPal recurring payments, however I don't seem to be getting the custom variable I set, through the IPN.

This is how I go through the express checkout:

```
$item = array(
    'subscription_description' => 'Monthly ' . $plan['title'] . ' subscription',
    'cost' => $plan['price'],
);
$options = array(
    'return' => $this->base . 'action/subscription/', // Confirmation URL
    'cancel' => $this->base . 'action/cancel/', // Cancellation URL
    'cost' => $plan['price'],
    'item_cost' => $plan['price'],
    'custom' => 999 //config('user:id')
);

$result = $this->paypal->getCheckoutUrl($options, $item);

if (is_string($result)) {
    //Redirection URL generated successfully! redirecting to Paypal
    header('Location: ' . $result);
}
```

if they complete the purchase they get redirected to my subscription page where I create the subscription profile:
$date = date('c', strtotime('+1 months')); //start next month

```
$profile = array(
    'period' => 'Month', // Subscription Period
    'frequency' => 1, // Frequency x period equals 1 billing cycle (up to 1 year)
    'total_cycles' => 12, // End profile after 1 year (12 cycles)
    // Regular subscription amount
    'start_date' => $date, // Profile start date
    'currency' => 'USD' // Payment currency
);

//select user info
$user = $this->Db->selectOne(array('id' => config('user:id')), 'users');

//get user's plan
$plan = $this->Db->selectOne(array('id' => $user['plan']), 'plans');

$profile['cost'] = $profile['init_amount'] = $plan['price'];
$profile['desc'] = 'Monthly ' . $plan['title'] . ' subscription';

$profileId = $this->paypal->createRecurringProfile($profile);
```

After that I receive the IPN with the txn_type of recurring_payment_profile_created but the custom variable is missing.. Any ideas? How am I supposed to track which of my users signed up for the subscription?

**Edit:** The IPN message

```
Array
(
    [payment_cycle] => Monthly
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment_profile_created
    [last_name] => Bernotas
    [initial_payment_status] => Completed
    [next_payment_date] => 03:00:00 Mar 28, 2013 PDT
    [residence_country] => GB
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.01
    [currency_code] => USD
    [time_created] => 08:52:45 Feb 28, 2013 PST
    [verify_sign] => xxxx
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [payer_status] => verified
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_email] => xxxx
    [first_name] => Ignas
    [receiver_email] => xxxx
    [payer_id] => xxxx
    [product_type] => 1
    [initial_payment_txn_id] => xxxx
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [amount_per_cycle] => 0.01
    [profile_status] => Active
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.7
    [amount] => 0.01
    [outstanding_balance] => 0.00
    [recurring_payment_id] => xxxxx
    [product_name] => Monthly Basic subscription
    [ipn_track_id] => xxx
)
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI, your link to the Lionlite page doesn't work. If I open it from SO, it returns me to SO, and if I open it in a new tab, it returns me to their frontpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have appears to be correct.  I tested this as well with recurring payments on my system, and the custom variable does not appear to be getting sent back in the IPN.  I would suggest opening up a ticket with PayPal MTS at www.paypal.com/mts for a possible bug with this.  This way, by opening up a ticket you will also be notified once the issue is resolved.

Comment: I hate paypal. I truly hate it.. Thanks for the tip. Was hoping I was just missing something..

Comment: What if I used the profileID i get on the subscription page as a token to bind payments to users? Would that cause issues?

Comment: There are other variables that you can use that may not be being used.  I can think of "DESC" or "BUSINESS" off hand.  You can could pass your information over in one of these variables and then use it accordingly once it is returned back to your site.

Comment: But wouldn't that be visible to the user though? I think it must be the profileID i'll need to use

Comment: To sort this out I just store the profile id when users get redirected back to my success page and then on IPN calls I match it. Cheers for the help. Will have to submit an issue to paypal when I'll have more time.